# How to make the value of an object of an array as the key of an object of another array

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have an array like this:

```
array1 = [
{date: '1', text: 'a'},
{date: '2', text: 'b'},
{date: '3', text: 'a'},
{date: '4', text: 'b'}
];
// text will be either 'a' or 'b'
// basically, here date denotes the dates of a month, so it could be up to 28 or 29 or 30 or 31
```

Now I want to convert this array to something like following array

```
array2 = [
{1: '1'},
{2: '0'},
{3: '1'},
{4: '0'}
];
// For each value of array1, value of date (1,2,3,4) becomes keys here. If text was 'a', it should convert to '1' and if it was 'b', it should convert to '0'.
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const array2 = array1.map(value => {
   let newValue;
   if(value.text === 'a') {
      newValue = 1;
   } else if(value.text === 'b') {
      newValue = 0;
   }
   let newObj = {};
   newObj[value.date] = newValue;
   return newObj;
});
```

You can use this code for the output you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Just iterate through *Array1*, check if the text is 'a', then store 1 else store 0.

```js
const array1 = [
{date: '1', text: 'a'},
{date: '2', text: 'b'},
{date: '3', text: 'a'},
{date: '4', text: 'b'}
];

let newArray = {};

for(let i=0; i<array1.length; i++){
    if(array1[i]["text"] === 'a'){
    newArray[array1[i]["date"]] = 1;
  } else {
    newArray[array1[i]["date"]] = 0;
  }
}

console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `mapper` object which maps `text` value to the number. Then use `map` on the array:

```js
const array = [{date:"1",text:"a"},{date:"2",text:"b"},{date:"3",text:"a"},{date:"4",text:"b"}],
      mapper = { a: '1', b: '0' },
      output = array.map(o => ({ [o.date]: mapper[o.text] }))

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple one-liner would be:

```js
const array1 = [
  {date: '1', text: 'a'},
  {date: '2', text: 'b'},
  {date: '3', text: 'a'},
  {date: '4', text: 'b'}
];

const array2 = array1.map(({date, text}) => ({[date]: text === "a" ? "1" : "0"}))

console.log(array2)
```